# 91 Buick Regal radio/amp replacement

Tags: audio, buick, electronics

I have a 91 Buick Regal sedan that some part of the car stereo has died on. It turns on but I cannot get any audio out of it. It seems that the radio and amp are contained in one unit under the glove box. Is this correct or is the amp elsewhere? The unit I found has a model number of #(GM)16072800. If the radio and amp are contained in one unit, will I be able to replace it with something like the BOSS Audio 612UA directly or will I need a separate amp or different wiring harness? I realize that if I use the 612UA I will need to figure out cable extensions In order to to put in the center of the console.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I posted this here because I thought it was more directly related to vehicle oem equipment but if there's a better place for this question please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

the 16072800 is your radio and amp.  The display is separate.  I can not say for sure if you could replace it with an aftermarket unit without seeing behind the stereo to see if there is clearance.  The factory one is only maybe 2 inches deep.    Your best bet in my opinion is to hit ebay and buy a known working module.  There's three or four of them on there for as low as $35.

You could probably find one in a junkyard as well.  that module came in an extensive list of vehicles.  You can find the list on this listing on ebay:  https://www.ebay.com/itm/88-89-90-91-92-93-94-Sunbird-Reciever-Amplifier-AMP-Tuner-16072800/283015572224?hash=item41e50aeb00:g:6I4AAOSwrxtbKV2P:rk:4:pf:0  Note though that there are much cheaper listings so don't buy this one.

Comment: So regardless of the room available, it is possible to replace it with a after market stereo. I had heard somewhere that I would need to buypass the oem amp.

Comment: the "oem amp" is actually the remote innards for the radio.  You need to remove both the faceplate and the module.